# ClassNotFoundException when compiling JRXML with Maven

Tags: java, maven, jasper-reports

I use in my JRXML some object of my application **A** like this :

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ResportTest" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5394743546921226"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<import value="com.test.app.EnumOne"/>
<import value="com.test.app.Test1DTO"/>
<import value="com.test.app.Test1Sub1DTO"/>
<import value="com.test.app.Test1Sub2DTO"/>
<import value="com.test.app.Test2DTO"/>
<import value="com.test.app.EnumTwo"/>
```

With iReport, i have added my *target/classes* directory to classpath, everythink is OK.

Now, when i try to compile my JRXML with maven (mvn clean install), i've got an error :

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.949 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-04-10T08:17:26+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 39M/112M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jasperreports-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1:compile-reports (default) on project projectOne: Error co
mpiling report design : C:\ws\projectOne\src\main\resources\jasper\jrxml\ReportTest.jrxml: Error compiling report d
esign : C:\ws\projectOne\src\main\resources\jasper\jrxml\ReportTest.jrxml : Report design not valid :
[ERROR] 1. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.app.EnumOne
[ERROR] 2. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.app.EnumTwo
[ERROR] 3. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.app.Test2DTO
```

When my build fail, maven had already compile all classe in target/classes.
I don't undestand why maven can't find EnumOne, EnumTwo and Test2DTO when it can find the other.

Here my pom.xml for jasper:

```
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jasperreports-plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources/jasper/jrxml</sourceDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>src/main/resources/jasper/jasper</outputDirectory>
                    <compiler>net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJavacCompiler</compiler>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.jasperreports}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i just found the solution.
Maven use the dependency jasperreports-maven-plugin with version **1.0-beta-1**. I upgraded the dependency to **1.0-beta-2** and it now works !